# overflow in div for image drag and drop

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am dragging an image onto a **div** using javascript and html5.

And later doing the resizing of the image .

But the issue is even if I make use of the overflow:hidden and any of the properties of overflow, the image is coming out of the div . How to make it be inside the div itself?

```
<script>




function allowDrop(ev) {

        ev.preventDefault();

    }

    function drag(ev) {

        ev.dataTransfer.setData("application/json", JSON.stringify([ev.target.id,(ev.offsetX || ev.clientX - $(ev.target).offset().left),(ev.offsetY || ev.clientY - $(ev.target).offset().top)]));

    }

    function drop(ev) {

        ev.preventDefault();

        var data = JSON.parse(ev.dataTransfer.getData("application/json"));

        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data[0]));

        //window.alert( ev.clientX + ',' + ev.clientY);

        document.getElementById("img").style.left = ev.clientX - data[1] + 'px';

        document.getElementById("img").style.top = ev.clientY - data[2] + 'px';

         document.getElementById("img").addEventListener('mousedown', initDrag, false);

        return false;   

     }

     var startX, startY, startWidth, startHeight;

        function initDrag(e) {  

            startX = e.clientX;

            startY = e.clientY; 

             startWidth = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("img")).width, 10);

            startHeight = parseInt(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("img")).height, 10);

            document.documentElement.addEventListener('mousemove', doDrag, false);

            document.documentElement.addEventListener('mouseup', stopDrag, false);

        }

        function doDrag(e) { 

         document.getElementById("drag2").style.width = (startWidth + e.clientX - startX) + 'px';

            document.getElementById("drag2").style.height = (startHeight + e.clientY - startY) + 'px';


         }

        function stopDrag(e) {

            document.documentElement.removeEventListener('mousemove', doDrag, false);

             document.documentElement.removeEventListener('mouseup', stopDrag, false);

        }
</script>

<body>



<div id="divid" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">



    </div>

     <img src="test.jpg" id="img" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"></img>

</body>

<style>

#divid {width:350px;height:170px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;overflow:auto;}

    #img {width:50px;height:50px;padding:10px;position: absolute;}
</style>
```

Comment: suggest creating a jsfiddle

Comment: I think You have `img` element outside the `div`

Comment: Initially the img is outside the div, after dragging it onto div , it comes within the div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're referring to your div that has id 'divid', your  tag is not inside the div. So, if you want the overflow settings of the div to apply to the image, the image element has to be before the  tag. Like:

```
<div id="divid" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <img src="test.jpg" id="img" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"></img>
</div>
```

EDIT: Okay, so I misunderstood the question a little with my previous answer. I'm leaving it for posterity's sake. After some testing, I found that the solution is really simple. You need to set your div's style to use position: relative. Otherwise, the absolutely positioned image will just ignore the div's overflow setting.
Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q9etbdxg/. Drag the test image so it straddles the edge of the div, and you should see scrollbars appear.

Comment: The basic image is always outside . I understand that , but after dragging the image onto the div dynamically, the image crosses the div's border after resizing it